# image won't show in tableView

Tags: android, android-emulator, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I'm creating a tableView in appcelerator (Android) and I want to add an image to it. This is just a test because I also had some problems with it in my project and I wanted to try it out first somewhere else so I wouldn't ruin my whole project.

I first added the standard png's to see if he would show those, and he did. But when I add a png that I've created, he refuses to show it in the tableView. Does someone know why he refuses to show the image? (I created that png in photoshop by changing one of the standard png's and adding my image to it.)

```
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title:'tableViewRow',
    backgroundColor:'#fff'
});

var regData = [
{leftImage:'KS_nav_ui.png', title:'gft', left:20, color:'black'},
{rightImage:'KS_nav_views.png', title:'grofvuil', left:20, color:'black'},
{leftImage:'glas.png', title:'glas', left:20, color:'black'}
];

var tbl = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    data:regData
});

win.add(tbl);
win.open();
```

Here's an image of the result I get in my android emulator (android api: Google APIs Android 2.2 and screen:HVGA)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it. What I did is I ran  the application in an android amulator. I closed the app and went back to the homescreen (where you can save some apps). I pressed on menu and went to the settings. Than I went to applications. I opened 'manage applications' and remove the application. I closed the emulator and ran it again and the images were shown.

I don't know why you have to do it, but it worked for me. I hope I can save someone the frustration by posting the answer (I know I had them :D)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AppC 1.8, you may just need a forward slash in your path '/'.  (or backward if Windows)

Comment: that's not it: I first tried it with an image I had made, it worked but was too small. So I made it bigger and replaced it. When I rebuild it, it wouldn't show the image anymore. That's the weird thing about it. It worked, replaced it and refused to work. Soooo weird :)

Comment: Now it is getting even more weird! So I deleted the launch configuration of that project and ran it. For some reason it launched with screen WVGA854 instead of HVGA and I saw the 3th image as well. But when I changed the screen to HVGA in the configuration, the image was gone.